# Regex Pattern to Match Certain Rules

Tags: regex, nfa

UPDATE: Turns out I am an idiot and misread the original problem. The original problems specifies that there must be AT MOST 3 of the 4 letters used, not AT LEAST. This completely changes the question and eliminates my doubts when creating the NFA and DFA. Sorry everyone and thanks for the help!

For a homework problem, I have to create a regex pattern that will match these specifications...

- Must be composed of only letters a, b, c, and d
- Must be in reverse alphabetical order
- Must use at least 3 of the 4 given letters (a,b,c,d that is, can have as many total letters as possible)

My answer that I am fairly confident about is (d+c+b+a*)|(d+b+a+)|(d+c+a+)|(c+b+a+). My first question is if this is correct. My second is if this expression can be simplified or altered at all.

The next step is to draw a graph for a non-deterministic finite automaton for the regex and I am having difficulty completing that step.

As requested, here is my attempt at an NFA (rough sketch)

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://regex101.com/) site. It's amazing for regex development and testing. If you want a graph, check out [this](http://regexper.com/) site.

Comment: Currently you expression matches "ddccbbaaaaaaa": but there is nothing in that specification to allow repeated letters. In most regex dialects `?` matches 0 or 1 instances.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. ddccbbaa.. is fine. As long as the characters are in reverse alphabetical order, aka, no dcbab

Comment: Is it for the whole line? Or should it match the first part of ddccddaa, or match both parts ?

Comment: In the scope of this question, I would not worry about repeats in pattern. ddccddaa would fail as soon as the second instances of d's came along. I would think of it as just an input string that either passes or fails. dcbadcba will also fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer was fine to me.

There are 5 kinds of patterns to match:

```
d+c+b+a+
c+b+a+
d+b+a+
d+c+a+
d+c+b+
```

`(d+c+b+a+)|(c+b+a+)|(d+b+a+)|(d+c+a+)|(d+c+b+)`,which could be in the following forms by merging the first pattern to the sub-fours:

```
(d+c+b+a*)|(d+b+a+)|(d+c+a+)|(c+b+a+) OR
(d*c+b+a+)|(d+b+a+)|(d+c+a+)|(d+c+b+) ...
```

A quite straight forward way to me:

```
(d*c+b+a+)|(d+c*b+a+)|(d+c+b*a+)|(d+c+b+a*)
```

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to type the + after the a in the last option (fixed now). I had it originally and must have forgotten to type it out. 

Excuse me if I am incorrect, but isn't your regex a less simplified version of mine? For example, why do you need the d* in (d* c+b+a+) since the other three options encompass all the other alternatives that start with d. The d* seems completely unnecessary. Same with c* in the next one and so on

Comment: OMG, This way is more straight forward, easy to understand to me. Then, what are you looking for?

Comment: My answer seemed a bit clunky and I thought it may be possible to simplify it further. This is mainly because I am having issues constructing a nondeterministic FA and deterministic FA in the next steps so I wanted to verify my Regex was at least correct.

Comment: None of the `*`s are necessary `/(c+b+a+)|(d+b+a+)|(d+c+a+)|(d+c+b+)/` would work the same for the question or if it were needed then you should add anchor points to the start and end.@fapple What is a `FA`?

Comment: What about the `dcba`? @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９

Comment: That would be matched as you have no anchors.

Comment: A FA is a finite automata. The next step is an NFA which can include lambda transitions. I can upload a rough sketch of my attempt if that would be helpful.

I think your comment about there not being anchors may tie into my struggles with my FA's...mainly because I have an issue with the DCBA testcase. After DCB, it should already be in the finished state with any additional B's or A's simply looping back into the finished state. However, how can I draw this out while also accommodating the possibility of a DCA case?

Comment: I got you. But this may match `xcba` as well, my answer failed the same way.  This question is more about `finite automata` than `regex`. @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９

Comment: Sorry it took so long, my phone was being very uncooperative. I added a sketch of my NFA above. 

Also, as far as there being anchors, wouldn't I still need to specify a* at the end of dcb since I am still limited to these 4 letters? Wouldn't want to match dcbz right?

Comment: FYI you don't need any brackets in your last regex

Comment: Yep, more clear to me this way. Maybe the no capture way?  Maybe there is not that much need to care this right now.@Bohemian

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify (a little) by noting that only input starting with `d+c+` have flexibility of 3 or 4 letters:

```
^(d+c+(b+a*|b*a+)|d+b+a+|c+b+a+)$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/3mGM3OVeo9).